# Does prefetching work with Service Bus Trigger?

Tags: c#, azureservicebus, azure-durable-functions

I have a Durable orchestration client which is Service Bus Topic triggered.

```
[FunctionName("ServiceBusTrigger")]
        public static async Task ServiceBusTrigger(
            [ServiceBusTrigger("topicname", "subscriptionname", Connection = "MyServiceBusKey")]string mySbMsg,
            [OrchestrationClient]DurableOrchestrationClient starter,
            ILogger log)
        {
            string instanceId = await starter.StartNewAsync("Orchestrator", mySbMsg);

            log.LogInformation($"Started orchestration with ID = '{instanceId}'.");

        }
```

Does enabling the prefetch count under extensions in `host.json` cause messages to be prefetched in the Service Bus Trigger?

`host.json`:

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "extensions": {
        "serviceBus": {
            "prefetchCount": 100
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Does enabling the prefetch count under extensions in host.json cause messages to be prefetched in the Service Bus Trigger?

Prefetch count affects the maximum number of messages prefetched by the underlying `MessageReceiver` used by Azure Functions SDK. You will have to ensure that `prefetchCount` is configured properly with the value defined for `maxConcurrentCalls` to ensure not too many messages are pre-fetched and locks are lost while waiting for processing.

Comment: Does this mean that if `prefetchCount` is set to 200 and `maxConcurrentCalls` is set to say 16, 200 messages will be prefetched to a specific instance, but only 16 messages will be processed at a time?

Comment: Correct. `MessageSender` gets the messages prefetched (200), but the client code will only process up to `MaxConcurrency` (16).

Comment: Are there any limits to `maxConcurrentCalls`? Is there anything that prevents us from setting `prefetchCount` equal to `maxConcurrentCalls`?

Comment: `MaxConcurrentCalls` is how many messages will be processed concurrently by a single `MessageReceiver`. `PrefetchCount` is up to how many messages a single `MessageReceiver` will retrieve when making a call to receive a message. Setting those two to the same value is counterproductive. `PrefetchCount` should be larger than the number of messages processed concurrently.

Comment: @SeanFeldman If we are having multiple azure function is there a way we can have different prefetch and concurrency for different trigger on the same function app ? and if there are two functions and the concurrency is kept to 15  will both the functions have concurrency as 15 or it will be divided between the functions ?

Comment: Prefetch count and concurrency are per message receiver. A message receiver is per entity (queue or subscription). If you have more than one function and those work with different entities, then the settings are **per entity/function**.